# How do I Americanize "Fat lot of good X will do you"?

Tags: phrase-usage, phrase-request, american-english, british-english, colloquial-language

I learned British English, but I work exclusively with Americans. I'll often say "Fat lot of good X did for us", and I get confused looks from others. For example, the other day, I said "I think we should have had them take the web development course; fat lot of good the algorithms course did for them" and people have no idea what I mean. A coworker told me that what I'm saying sounds like what someone British would say, and I'm not sure how to Americanize this statement.

First: Am I using the term "Fat lot of good" incorrectly? Second: How should I say this in American English?

Comment: It's strictly "**a** fat lot of good..." but dropping the `a` is perfectly acceptable - to a Brit. idk what the US equivalent would be, sorry.

Comment: I'm an American, and I certainly understand "Fat lot of good X did for us".   But I watched British TV and read British literature...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Just leave out the fat**, in speech, and use a sarcastic tone.

"I think we should have had them take the web development course; a lot of good the algorithms course did for them."

The fact is that this is an idiomatic expression.

And **many Americans** *would in fact understand*
"a fat lot of good". Who cares what a coworker says?  The expression is not essentially British at all.

It's in Merriam Webster like this:

a (fat) lot of good
idiom
informal
: no use or help at all
"I've brought an umbrella." "A (fat) lot of good that will do now that it's stopped raining!"

[Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/a%20%28fat%29%20lot%20of%20good)

Answer (score 1):

Chicagoan here. While this is something any American who's read a British book should have no difficulty with, if I were writing dialogue for an American character I'd probably have them say a few different things depending on the level of politeness they're going for.

"I think we should have had them take the web development course— the algorithms course did_______ for them"

- *nothing* - neutral.
- *absolutely nothing* - neutral in content, but you're clearly annoyed by how useless the course was.
- *jack shit* - mildly rude, but funny. casual.
- *jack* - leaving out the curseword is understood to mean the same thing, but more politely. still casual.
- *fuck all* - rude, but funny. definitely use only with friends.

Notice I just dropped the "a lot of good the..." part.

Answer (score 0):

A whole lot of good would also work. I'm guessing the confusion comes from the fact that "fat" generally refers to being overweight.